# Hide excel-viewer toolbar and disable editing

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my React TS module used https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel-viewer as below.

```
new ExcelViewer(ref.current, "Book1.xlsx", {theme: "light", themeBtn: false});
```

```
<div className="excel-viewer" ref={ref} />
```

Since it is used only for viewing xlsx file, I need to hide its toolbar and make spreadsheet read only so that not able to edit spread sheet.

Any solution to do this is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can modify the [soucre code](https://github.com/SuperYesifang/excel-viewer/blob/master/src/ExcelViewer.js#L55) of excel-viewer, add config

```js
mode: 'read',
showToolbar: false,
```